# Properly stopping, waiting, and reseting a node.js heroku process

Tags: node.js, heroku

I haven't deployed yet, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have an app that uses a lot of background processes. That is, even after a response is sent, there are still functions associated with that response executing in the background. Thus, I want to do something like this:

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(80)

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  server.close()
  setTimeout(function () {
    process.exit()
  }, 30000) // Wait 30 seconds before exiting
})
```

I'm not sure if this is correct or not. More assumptions:

- These background processes are crucial. However, they'll probably take 1-2 seconds, not 30 seconds. Still, I want to put a 30 second delay just for safety.
- This should work for both restarting the process (say, with forever) and stopping the process
- What signals does Heroku (or any other process) send to node.js through `process`? Would I have to handle them any differently?
- Would I handle `uncaughtException` any differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it. Heroku sends a `SIGTERM` signal when shutting down. If the process doesn't exit in 10 seconds, then it sends a `SIGKILL` signal. Thus, the following is sufficient:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', server.close.bind(server))
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm

Assuming 10 seconds is enough for the background processes to complete.

Basically, send a "close" signal x seconds before a "exit" signal and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you better use a worker process for doing those background jobs (worker dyno on Heroku).

this both free your web server to serve your users as fast as possible and allow you to have better control when scaling (for example, running 3 web dynos and 2 worker dynos).

you can use Redis's pub/sub functionality to submit jobs to the worker dyno (or use a library to do so, such as http://learnboost.github.com/kue/ ).

this way, when a web dyno restarts/dies/etc.. it doesn't have any effect on pending background jobs and when a worker dyno restarts it'll just consume pending jobs and process them, so you don't loose any jobs because of restarting.

Comment: 1. These jobs are db tasks so I don't see a point in using workers. By the time I queue the job it could already be done. 2. I'm not going to add another database. 3. I don't want multiple stacks.

Comment: so implement something similar to a jobs queue, so when a dyno restarts it processes pending jobs and you don't loose anything due to the restart. IMHO its a much more robust strategy then setting a timeout and hoping that nothing get killed. (you'll also be covered in case the machine completely dies without killing the process)

Comment: answer is much simpler - listen to the `SIGTERM` event instead of `SIGINT` or `SIGKILL`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm