# How heroku stops running script before deploy new version?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

How heroku stops running script before deploy new version?

I was trying to save volatile data before application kill using this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kvs-sync

But unfortunately heroku is not allowing using filesystem (readonly).

How can I detect this event to save any variables stored in memory?
Or should I save it on every change?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16291605/3284355 heroku sends a SIGTERM and you have 30 seconds to close your app. I haven't found any info about *read-only* though.

Comment: Thanks man! I didnt read this.
I was trying to use not async functions to make sure saving data, but if I have 30 secs after SIGTERM that solves my problem.

Comment: Heroku's filesystem isn't read-only; it's [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). You can write to it, but anything that you write won't survive a Dyno restart (which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't count on any state surviving Heroku restarts. I would use a DB for anything that needs to be persistent. If your data is simple, relatively small and you need very high performance use Redis. For more complex data you can use Mongo, Couch, Rethink or any DB really, relational or not.